# matlabs stops working with execution of audiorecorder

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, audio-recording

I am new to signal processing in matlab. I want to record audio from microphone. I have used the following code:

```
    myaudio = audiorecorder(44100,16,1);
    disp('Please Speak');
    record(myaudio,5);
    stop(myaudio);
    output = play(myaudio);
```

Upon running this code, most of the times matlab stops working. Sometimes it works but ends up showing an error 'Recorder is empty'. Please help in solving the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A quick workaround to the empty recorder problem is to add `pause([recording length])` between `record` and `stop`. See here:

[Why do I receive an error when attempting to record data using AUDIORECORDER in MATLAB 7.8 (R2009a)?](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-A7JLKG/?product=ML&solution=1-A7JLKG)